# Keep the Path between Windows and 'Bash on Ubuntu on Windows' in sync

Tags: windows, bash, shell, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

What's the best way to keep the Windows 10 Path and the 'Bash on Ubuntu on Windows (WSL)' Path in sync?

I have appended the Windows 10 Path (converted it to bash compatible) to .bashrc but the bash shell doesn't appear to be picking it up.

Steps I took:

1. Get Windows Path >echo %PATH%
2. Pick the relevant paths and convert to
   bash compatible (e.g. C:\Java becomes /mnt/c/Java )
3. Start bash & edit .bashrc
4. Append to .bashrc e.g.> 
   export PATH=${PATH}:/bin:/mnt/c/Java/bin:/mnt/c/node

Comment: May I ask you what's the point in doing this? You can't run Windows executables from Ubuntu anyway. Having said this, I wouldn't do the transformation in bash, but write an auxiliary program in a language with better string handling capabilities (Ruby, Perl, ....). If you want to do it in bash, I suggest that you split the Windows path on semicolons, transform each path component separately, and join the path together again with a colon as separator.

Comment: @user1934428 You've been able to invoke Windows apps from within Bash since Insider build 14951: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/10/19/interop-between-windows-and-bash/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Insider build 145963 (ish), you don't need to append the Windows path in your .bashrc:

In subsequent builds, and from Creators Update onwards, WSL automatically appends the Windows path to your Bash path, allowing you to launch Windows executables from within Bash without needing to enter the absolute folder location to executables that are on the path.

For example, navigate to a temp folder on your C: drive, create a text file and open it in notepad:

```
$ cd /mnt/c/temp
$ echo Hello > hello.txt
$ Notepad.exe ./hello.txt
```

> Tip: Don't forget the `.exe` extension - that's what tells Linux to ask WSL to launch the .exe

Comment: A late question for you please: If I use [something that will install something and adapt the path] dpkg or linuxbrew in the bash, will that reflect the PATH changes back to windows, or will I have to copypaste that? I am asking because for some dev project all I got is a very convoluted setup with a thousand flags "not sure if that works under windows" and then "or just use my homebrew script...". Thanks!

Comment: No - your Linux path is not exposed to Windows - only the other way around; your Windows path is appended to your Linux path in Bash. You should avoid navigating into the Linux file-system via Windows tools. Instead, access your Windows files from Bash if you want to share files across the Windows-Linux boundary

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you wish you had.

That automaticly convert your Windows PATH to Bashrc:

https://github.com/hypolas/wintobashpath

https://github.com/hypolas/wintobashpath/releases/tag/v1.0.0

```
echo %PATH%
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\;C:\Program Files\nodejs;;E:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Go\bin;C:\Users\hypolas\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\hypolas\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;E:\msys64-2023\mingw64\bin;C:\Users\hypolas\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\hypolas\go\bin
```

Became:

```
/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/hypolas/bin:/c/Users/hypolas/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/hypolas/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/c/Program Files/dotnet:/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/c/Program Files/PowerShell/7:/c/Program Files/nodejs
```

I do that for myself.